# take some text in blade for request Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to take a value (B{{ $some_y_len + 1 }}) in tag < object >  as request in Controller?I already add 'name' attribute in this tag. But It either isn't working or null in my Controller.php files. This code is in blade.php :

```
<div class="alert alert-default" role="alert">
            <h2 style="color: aliceblue;"><strong>+- {{ 7*($some_y_len) }} menit</strong> ({{ $some_y_len}} Antrean)</h2> <br>
            No. antrean sekarang :<object name="no_some_y"><strong> B{{ $some_y_len + 1 }} </strong></object><br>
            Rata-rata  Tiap Antrean : <strong> 9 menit</strong>
        </div>
```

and its in Controller.php, I took for store() functions. Because this request value would store to database

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $string = $request->service;
    $id = (int)substr($string, 0,2);
    if ($string == "--Select One--"){
        Alert::error('Error', 'Pilihan Layanan Tidak Valid');
        return back();
    }

    else {

        $no_antre = "";
        if ($id == 1){
            $no_antre = $request->no_some_x;
        }
        else if ($id == 2) {
            $no_antre = $request->no_some_y;
        }
        else if ($id == 3) {
            $no_antre = $request->no_some_z;
        }
        else if ($id == 4) {
            $no_antre = $request->no_some_w;
        }

        dd($request->no_samsat);
        $user = Auth::user();
        $services = Miniproject::create([
        'instansi_id' => $id,
        'jenis_layanan' => $request->service,
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'no_antrian' => $no_antre
        ]);


        Alert::success('Success', 'Berhasil Mendapatkan Kode Antrian');

        return redirect('/miniproject');
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you define `$no_some_y_len`?

Comment: FIxed, thats my error.